# Separating D3 pie charts within a table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a HTML table of data being output by PHP, MySQL and Smarty, so the structure already exists - it's not being built by the D3 js.
Using [this guide](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111) as a template, I want to target specific td cells and add the charts. This is the code I have so far ...

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="d3chart v-155"></td>
    <td>Other data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="d3chart v-168"></td>
    <td>Other data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**
I've updated the JS and progressed to get the charts appearing in the corresponding cells (woohoo). I was having trouble appending the paths to the SVGs and this is now working. Please see the updated JS below ...

```js
// On ready call functions
$(function init() {
  ChartApp.init();
});

/** Interaction with D3 chart. Chart data is loaded directly into the template file  */
var ChartApp = {

  config: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    radius: 50, 
    data: [
      { cell:'v-155', score:82, extra:18 },
      { cell:'v-168', score:75, extra:25 }
    ],
    arcs: [
      [82,18],
      [75,25]
    ]
  },

  init: function() {

    // Insert an svg element for each row in our dataset. A child g
    // element translates the origin to the pie center.
    var svg = d3.select('body').select('svg')
        .data(ChartApp.config.data, function(d) { d3.select('.' + d.cell)
          .append('svg')
            .attr('width', ChartApp.config.width)
            .attr('height', ChartApp.config.height)
          .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ChartApp.config.radius + ',' + ChartApp.config.radius + ')')
          .append('text')
            .attr('dy', '.35em')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('fill', '#003580')
            .text(d.score);
        });

    // Define the pie layout
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        //.sort(null)
        .value(function(d) {
          console.log(d.score, d.extra);
          return (d.score, d.extra);
        });

    // Define the arc radius
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(ChartApp.config.radius / 1.6)
        .outerRadius(ChartApp.config.radius);

    // Define the color scale
    var colour = d3.scale.category20c();

    // Pass the data to d3.layout.pie to compute the angles for each arc.
    // These start and end angles are passed to d3.svg.arc to draw arcs.
    d3.selectAll('svg g').selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(ChartApp.config.data))
      //.data(function(d) {
      //  return pie(ChartApp.config.data);
      //})
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return colour(i); });
  }
};
```

However the charts are now being duplicated rather than iterating through the data array. Please if someone could help to either restructure the data or define a way to loop through each data element in the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution to this specific problem, in case it helps anyone else. There's bound to be a more 'D3' way of doing it, but this works for now. The markup has not changed and here is the upated JS that outputs D3 pie charts into corresponding table data cell rows ...

```
// On ready call functions
$(function init() {
  ChartApp.init();
});

/** Interaction with D3 chart. Chart data is loaded directly into the template file  */
var ChartApp = {

  config: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    radius: 50,
    data: [
      { cell:'v-155', score:45, extra:55 },
      { cell:'v-168', score:78, extra:22 },
      { cell:'v-173', score:76, extra:24 },
      { cell:'v-199', score:59, extra:41 },
      { cell:'v-177', score:75, extra:25 },
      { cell:'v-145', score:84, extra:16 },
      { cell:'v-156', score:82, extra:18 },
      { cell:'v-92', score:100, extra:0  },
      { cell:'v-162', score:80, extra:20 },
      { cell:'v-180', score:74, extra:26 }
    ]
  },

  init: function() {

    // Insert an svg element for each row in our dataset. A child g
    // element translates the origin to the pie center.
    var svg = d3.select('body').select('svg')
        .data(ChartApp.config.data, function(d) { d3.select('.' + d.cell)
          .append('svg')
            .attr('width', ChartApp.config.width)
            .attr('height', ChartApp.config.height)
          .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ChartApp.config.radius + ',' + ChartApp.config.radius + ')')
          .append('text')
            .attr('dy', '.35em')
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('fill', '#003580')
            .text(d.score);
        });

    // Define the pie layout
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null);

    // Define the arc radius
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(ChartApp.config.radius / 1.6)
        .outerRadius(ChartApp.config.radius);

    // Define the color scale
    var colour = d3.scale.category20c();

    // Loop through the data and for each element attach the paths for the specific data points
    for (let x = 0; x < ChartApp.config.data.length; x++) {
      d3.select('.' + ChartApp.config.data[x].cell).selectAll('svg g').selectAll('path')
      .data(pie([ChartApp.config.data[x].score, ChartApp.config.data[x].extra]))
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return colour(i); });
    }
  }
};
```

This code now loops through the data array to extract the correct data points for building a chart. I'm sure D3 can do this 'naturally' but it always seemed to be using the wrong values.